# ssh Permission denied (publickey) after upgrade Fedora 33

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, rsa, fedora

i have been trying many answers on this Stackoverlow questions same like i am asking now, but still can't resolve my problem, i am trying to clone by *ssh* but always got `Permission denied (publickey)`

when i run `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@bitbucket.org:myusername/my-api.git`

```
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:kkXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikLLLwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp2A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 18.205.93.2
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ktMzaalYyvU9Ev1bgELXatabkUkdcT828O0PppnNiV4M explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/alienwarepocket/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ktMzaalYyvU9Ev1bgELXatabkUkdcT828O0PppnNiV4M explicit agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

after i upgrade Fedora 33, i got this issue, it was no issue on Fedora 32

Comment: I suppose because of new installation your public key has changed. Can you try cloning via https?

Comment: that is a bug from Fedora 33 , i found it on Reddit , someone asked same kind error @Peaceful

Comment: Not a bug - Fedora 33 is now staunchly against weak cryptography.

Comment: You had accepted the right answer before.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the `update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:FEDORA32` command (which was part of the link I mentioned originally)

Comment: @Pocket Consider changing the accepted answer to avoid recommending a change in the crypto policies, but downgrade security per-host instead. ;-)

Comment: @Pocket Please consider keeping the accepted answer, which never recommented changing the crypto. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This could be related to "[Changes/StrongCryptoSettings2 in Fedora33](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/StrongCryptoSettings2)"

> The changes for default policy are:
>
> - Keep only TLS 1.2 (and TLS 1.3 when available) as enabled protocols and move the TLS 1.x, x<=1 to legacy level.
> - Require finite field parameters (RSA, Diffie-Hellman) of 2048 and more in the default settings
> - Disable SHA1 support for use in signatures (X.509 certificates, TLS, IPSEC handshakes)

The "[Upgrade/compatibility impact](http://Upgrade/compatibility%20impact)" section of the aforementioned link clearly mentions:

> It may be that the new settings break software that connects to servers which utilize weak algorithms.
> Compatibility can be obtained by switching the system to Fedora 32 policy level:
>
> ```
> update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:FEDORA32
> ```

**NOT RECOMMENDED** though: if you can use an ed25519, this is better.

As mentioned in [Peque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3577054/peque)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181716/6309), you can add on your `~/.ssh/config` an option initially found [`in sshd_config`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html)

```
 PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
         Specifies the key types that will be accepted for public key
         authentication as a list of comma-separated patterns.
```

So if you cannot use ed25519, you can, for one specific host, allow the use of `id_rsa` keys with:

```
Host aHost
    Hostname a.hostname.com
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

---

Finally: Double-check your permissions after upgrade:

- `~/.ssh` is `775` `drwxrwxr-x`.
- `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is `600` `-rw-------`.
- `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is `644` `-rw-r--r--`.
- `~/.ssh/config` is `600` `-rw-------`.
- `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on remote server is `600` `-rw-------`

But using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` keys seems to be recommended now.

Comment: to set default like previous fedora, that is not recommended because the new in fedora 33 more secure,

Comment: @Pocket Yes, I just edited the answer to clearly state it is not recommended.

Comment: Regenerating a key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` fixed my problem with bitbucket.org.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Please add to the description that the permissions of ~/.ssh/config should be 600

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

@VonC Is correct, I upgraded to fedora 33 and ran into this permission issue.

running the following command fixed it :

```
update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:FEDORA32
```

Thank you for sharing that article

Comment: I updated to Fedora 33 and ran into the same issue. This solution worked for me when using a repository on bitbucket

Comment: This solution, on Fedora 33, worked for me using repository on gitlab

Comment: To be clear, this solution says "I'm okay with using weak cryptography" whereas VonC's solution fixes the root problem and uses strong cryptography to make Fedora 33 happy.

Comment: It is far better to use `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` for the servers that you need, instead of globally changing the policy. This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007312/520567

Answer (score 9):

Instead of globally changing the crypto policies, it is better to downgrade security per-host.

You can update the configuration for the specific legacy host in your `.ssh/config` file by adding:

```
Host legacy.host
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

For more details, have a look at this [discussion in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1884920).

Comment: I followed the link, thanks for that, and it had `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa` - so slightly different, but it worked for me on Fedora 34.