# In Fedora 33, git operations with ssh id_rsa file fail on GitLab.com

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, gitlab

Since I've installed Fedora 33, any git operation with GitLab.com (and with a different symptom, azure) fail. On GitLab.com I get:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Azure simply asks for password without showing any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-com-ssh-blocking-me/45535/2), the fix for gitlab is to save these lines in `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

For Azure, change both occurrences of `gitlab.com` to `ssh.dev.azure.com`