# git(1) CLI on Fedora-33 requesting a password after creating a SSH keypair and adding it to Azure DevOps (or GitHub) - (steps below)

Tags: git, azure, ssh, azure-devops, fedora

After setting up a `SSH` key for `GIT` in `Azure DevOps`, the following test command ...

`user@fedora33$ ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com`

is still prompting me for a password (as demonstrated further below).

In bullet form, here's what I did so you can help me. (Thank you in advance).

1. `cd ${HOME}/.ssh/`
2. `user@fedora33$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f id_rsa.azdevops`
3. `vi ./config  # And entered in the following snippet:`

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
    Hostname ssh.dev.azure.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.azdevops
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User FirstName.LastName
```

Next, I added the generated `SSH` key to `Azure DevOps` here (using the add wizard):

`https://dev.azure.com/<OrgName>/_usersSettings/keys`

and pasted the contents of `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa.azdevops.pub` into it's `Public Key Data` box.

Permissions on and within `${HOME}/.ssh/` are properly tightened:

```
5242887 4 drwx------  2 user  user  4096 Jan 20 13:04 .ssh
5252250 4 -rw-------  1 user  user  1238 Jan 20 13:04 .ssh/config
5242899 4 -rw-------  1 user  user  3381 Jan 20 13:01 .ssh/id_rsa.azdevops-ssh.ZAAPS
5242910 4 -rw-r--r--  1 user  user   741 Jan 20 13:01 .ssh/id_rsa.azdevops-ssh.ZAAPS.pub
```

Still, a password is being requested:

```
user@fedora33$ ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
```

I've done this a million times before. Why is it asking for a password now?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64675639/7976758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just as I completed this step-by-step question, I found that, as of `Fedora-33`, an extra `K/V` pair -- `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa` -- is now required in `${HOME}/.ssh/config`:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa   <--- Required as of Fedora-33 (Global scope)

Host ssh.dev.azure.com
    Hostname ssh.dev.azure.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.azdevops
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa   <--- Required as of Fedora-33 (Host scope)
    User FirstName.LastName
```

I should also mention that this isn't an `Azure DevOps` specific issue. I reproduced the same with `GitHub`. So this was an entirely    `Fedora-33` version related issue.

I lost 4-hours on this esoteric issue, so I hope this helps others! =:)