# failing with tls insuffiecent security

Tags: http, go

So far the code

```
        http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, Certificates: []tls.Certificate{certificate},  RootCAs: cacert,}
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/restconf/data/", cfgmgr_ip), nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.WithError(err).Errorf("Getrunningconfig: Failed to create request: %s", err)
                return "", ""
        }
        req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/yang-data+json")
        req.SetBasicAuth("admin","admin")
```

getting the below error

```
remote error: tls: insufficient security level
```

Any idea How it can be resolved?
I have verified the certs and tried manually it is working.

Comment: This is a TLS alert send by the server. It basically says that security provided is not sufficient, w/o providing any more details. Details why the server complains might be found at the server side in some logs, but based on the provided information one can only speculate. It could for example be that the provided client certificate does not match the servers expectations regarding key size or signature algorithm.

Comment: the server is golang creating pod with tls1.2.

Answer (score 0):

The more common error message is:

```
Error performing TLS handshake: 
One of the involved algorithms has insufficient security level
```

It depends on the server, for instance a [Fedora 33 would have a stronger crypto setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64675639/6309).

So it depends on the server.

[`rabbitmq/cluster-operator` PR 124](https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/pull/124) illustrates:

> I tried using a single self-signed CA cert and key as both the CA cert and the server cert, but this hit the issue that is documented here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#key-usage-effects-on-cipher-suites
>
> The issue states that the server cert should have in its `keyUsages` (a section in the certificate) `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment`, or some ciphers may be filtered out affecting the validation of the certs.
>
> I ran into the error: `tls: insufficient security level`.
> I could not find an easy way using [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl) to add the required keyUsages to the CA cert which may fix the problem too.
>
> Instead, I went for creating another cert that is signed by the CA.
> This will also be useful for mTLS where we can create the client cert similarly.